# Exporting embeddings per epoch in Keras

Tags: vector, keras, callback, embedding, word-embedding

I am trying to get access to the output of the embedding layer (the n-dimensional vectors) in Keras on a per epoch basis. There doesn't seem to be a specific callback for this. I 've tried the Tensorboard callbacks since it provides an option for logging the embeddings on each epoch but when I find the log files, I can't read them. They are probably files that can be accessed only by Tensorboard for visualization purposes. I need the embedding vectors to be saved in a format I can use later on outside keras, like a TSV file. Is there a way I could do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out how to do this, with much needed help from Nazmul Hasan on how to format the name to be updated with each epoch. Essentially I created a custom callback:

```
import io

encoder = info.features['text'].encoder

class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        out_v = io.open('vecs_{}.tsv'.format(epoch), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        vec = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0] # skip 0, it's padding.
        out_v.write('\t'.join([str(x) for x in vec]) + "\n")
        out_v.close()
```